# Is there a better way to check for KeyErrors when processing output from csv.DictReader()?

Tags: python, csv

I have a very long (100+ columns) CSV file to process.  Sometimes the people that generate the file make mistakes in the names of columns.  If they make a mistake would just like to ignore that column so I have this very long block of code where I check for `KeyError` on each piece of data.

```
    cr = csv.DictReader(response)
    for row in cr:
        try:
            creation_time = row['Creation Time']
        except KeyError:
            creation_time = ''
        try:
            current_pm_active = row['Current Active']
        except KeyError:
            current_pm_active = ''
        try:
            current_pm_total = row['Current Total']
        except KeyError:
            current_pm_total = ''
        ... and so on and on ...
```

I suspect there is probably a better way to code this. Thanks!

Update. Thanks for the questions. The reason I am placing data into individual variables is that I will be inserting these values in the Django Model like so:

```
updated_vmt, created = Vmt.objects.update_or_create(
                cluster=cluster,
                added=datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
                defaults={
                    'current_pm_active'   : current_pm_active,
                    'current_pm_total'    : current_pm_total,
                    ... big long list ...
                }
            )
```

Comment: The real question here is why have a variable assigned to each column at all? Why not a more flexible list or another dict?

Answer (score 0):

Save your values in a dictionary instead of individual variables; use a dictionary for the mapping from the expected CSV columns to your "variable" names.  Now you can loop over those keys instead of having a bunch of `if` statements.

If you put the values in a dictionary keyed the way you have for `defaults`, then you can just use `defaults = my_dictionary_of_row_data` in your insert statement, avoiding another "big long list".

Answer (score -1):

You can use [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) to generate a DataFrame, and cycle through columns

Comment: Still needs a way to map column names to keys for insert statement, and doesn't really address bad column names.